# Flutter dependency error with google_map_location_picker

Tags: flutter, dart, version

I am getting the following error on version solving with `google_map_location_picker`:

> Because google_map_location_picker 3.3.3 depends on intl >=0.16.0
> <=0.16.1 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends
> on intl 0.17.0, google_map_location_picker 3.3.3 is incompatible with
> flutter_localizations from sdk. So, because food_delivery_app depends
> on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and
> google_map_location_picker 3.3.3, version solving failed. pub get
> failed (1; So, because food_delivery_app depends on both
> flutter_localizations any from sdk and google_map_location_picker
> 3.3.3, version solving failed.)

Comment: You recently upgraded to flutter 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `pubspec.yaml` file set the version of `google_map_location_picker` to `any` (`google_map_location_picker: any`) then go to the `pubspec.lock` file and check the version of `google_map_location_picker` which solves the error.